# Why (unsigned char *) is used before the key term new in dynamic allocation

Tags: c++

I have encountered `charImage = (unsigned char *) new unsigned char [M*N]` in some tutorials for dynamically memory allocation of the 2D charImage. M and N are the row and columns numbers of the image.

**charImage** is declared as an unsigned char pointer at the beginning of the program.

What does the (unsigned char *) before **'new'** mean?

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: From your description it would appear to be a redundant C-style typecast.

Comment: I agree with Paul R. in the above code it is useless, increase verbosity, decrease maintenability, isn't C++. Please write only charImage=new unsigned char[M*N]

Comment: It means you should throw the tutorial away, and get a good book that lets you use `std::vector<unsigned char>`

Comment: and also it shouldn't be used in C++. Prefer some c++ casting like `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` in C++. as @Paul has said, it's useless in that command.

Answer (score 2):

It is a cast operator which can be used to convert one type to another. In this particular case its not required since the original variable is already an unsigned char. The cast will not do anything since types already match.

Comment: The operator is called a "cast", not a "type-cast".

Answer (score 0):

it means that you are allocating M*N unsigned bytes of memory and your `charImage` variabile is a pointer `*` to such array (a pointer to unsigned chars, so an `unsigned char *`)

if you look closely at your .h file you'll find the charImage variable defined as:

```
unsigned char *charImage;
```

Comment: It should be noted that the cast is redundant – and uses a dangerous, outdated style of cast.

Answer (score 0):

It's not required. The code is casting the returned pointer to the type of a pointer, so it's basically a no-op. If you delete it nothing bad will happen!

Answer (score 0):

It is a cast to a `unsigned pointer to char`.

Not only is is unneeded (`char[]` undergoes implicit conversion to a `char*` in your example), it is also a `C` style cast which is deprecated in `C++`.

If you do need to perform a cast in `C++` then you should use one of the following:

```
dynamic_cast<type>
static_cast<type>
reinterpret_cast<type>
const_cast<type>
```

Each performs a different role.

You can find one of many tutorials on the subject here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Answer (score 0):

Starting with C++11 you may use the term "auto" to salve some of the burden of re-typing the types of your object ( an making errors )

```
constexpr auto COLUMNS  = 640;
constexpr auto ROWS     = 480;

unsigned char  img[COLUMNS*ROWS];

// auto ptr_to_img = img; // or = &img[0]; //or see line below
auto ptr_to_img = new unsigned char[COLUMNS*ROWS];
```

You may also use Boost ( 1.56 ) Type Index library to tell you in most cases the type of your object

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

using std::cout;
using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;

//...

cout    << "COL type   : "
        << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(COLUMNS)>().pretty_name() << '\n';

cout    << "ROWS type  : "
        << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(ROWS)>().pretty_name() << '\n';

cout    << "Image type : "
        << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(img)>().pretty_name() << '\n';

cout    << "Ptr to Image type : "
        << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(ptr_to_img)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
```

The result is the following

```
COL type   : int const
ROWS type  : int const
Image type : unsigned char [307200]
Ptr to Image type : unsigned char*
```

Final remark is as usual that playing with raw pointers is discouraged in C++ as somewhere must exist the right container that will be specialized in storing image.

That object will be more easily managed by smart pointers ( the ones that will take care of automatically recovering the memory when you get rid off your image ).

This may be valid even when having to join to pure C library ( you convert to traditionnal form only at the interfaces of the C library )
But I have no knowledge of how C++ Image library solved this issue, this could be a question for this site.
Have a look before at some C++ image library. Boost has one too ( GIL ).